# how to get a recommand list from Apache PatriciaTrie

Tags: java

Now I want to get a recommand list from PatriciaTrie by using the prefix of words, my code like this:

```
 @Override
    public Response<List<ChannelSuggestionDTO>> getChannelSuggestion(SubSourceRequest request) {
        suggestions.put("ronak", 100.0);
        suggestions.put("ronald", 90.0);
        suggestions.put("robert", 200.0);
        suggestions.put("bat", 44.0);
        suggestions.put("batman", 440.0);
        Map.Entry<String, Double> entry = suggestions.select(request.getName());
        ChannelSuggestionDTO channelSuggestionDTO = new ChannelSuggestionDTO();
        channelSuggestionDTO.setName(entry.getKey());
        channelSuggestionDTO.setPriority(entry.getValue());
        List<ChannelSuggestionDTO> suggestionDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        suggestionDTOList.add(channelSuggestionDTO);
        return new Response<>(suggestionDTOList);
    }
```

now I could get one elment by prefix of words, but what should I do to get list of recommmad? for example, if I input a word start from 'r', it may return a list contains `ronak` \ `ronald` \ `robert`, is it possible to archive this?

Answer (score 0):

using `prefixMap` like this code:

```
    SortedMap<String, Double> sortedMap = GlobalData.suggestions.prefixMap(request.getName());
```